# Log all the activity of screen session to a file

Tags: logging

Is that possible to start a screen session on login of any users in Linux system and log each and every activity done by him in a file for later review or email that after his logout..

Basically, I want to see what an user does on the system what were the output of all the commands he ran.

I came across, script and sudosh tools but still working on them to configure them properly. If anyone has the experience with them, please guide me...

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) command in most Linux distributions which will record anything happening in the respective shell session.

What exactly was your problem with `script`? What kind of shell actions do you want to record?

Comment: I want to record all the commands run on shell and output as well.
Any URL or reference manual would be much appreciated!!

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're facing. You can simply use `script` as login shell for the users whose session you want to record. For trying it simply run the `script` command, do some things in that session, and after exiting it take a look at the file `typescript`.